# Compare Two List<Objects>

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best route to compare 2 `List<MyClasses>`?

List 2 could contain more values than List 1 which is ok. Just need to make sure List 2 contains everything in List 1. They also won't be in the same order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Except` to find the set difference of two collections.

```
var hasAllItems = !list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

Comment: I assume `List<Object>` is a `List<CustomType`.

Comment: The most suitable and perfect solution, I think that the function `GetHashCode` needed to be implemented also if you're using a custom object in your `List`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I assume you're insinuating that the objects may not have a sensible definition of equality defined.  To that, it's not sure if that's the case or not.  if it is, pretty much any solution will have that issue.  I consider defining proper equality for the type (if it's needed) a separate problem.

Comment: @Servy: yes, you're right. That is what i wanted to point out. And you're also right that the other approaches have the same problem. It's just important to mention especially because OP probably doesn't use known types which implement `Equals`+`GetHashCode`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sure, mentioning it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Didn't you mean `list1.Except(list2)`?

Answer (score 1):

This will let you know if list2 does not contain an item that is in list1:

```
list1.Any(x => !list2.Contains(x));
```

You could put it in a variable so you don't have to think about the double negatives:

```
var list2ContainsList1 = !list1.Any(x => !list2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter, updated.  Put in a variable to resove double negative issues.

Comment: @AaronPalmer: now it's even incorrect. You are checking if at least one object in List1 is not in List2 but the variable means the opposite. This is exactly the problem i've meant ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, sorry, it's been a long day.  *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
List1.All(o => List2.Contains(o));
```

This says "return true if and only if every item in list 1 is contained in list 2"

Comment: My apologies, I have switched the variable names to match the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (in your case, you don't care about the order of your elements in the lists):

```
var elementsInList2NotInList1 = list2.Except(list1);
```

Remember that this method uses a [default equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare the values. If you do care about the ordering of the elements, you'll need to do extra work, in order to check how each element of a list is equal to an element of the other list. The extra work would be the following:

1. Create your own comparer, implementing the interface [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
2. Create your own [`Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods for your custom data type.

Comment: How is this answer adding value compared to the other answers that already exist? [Servy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22182676/238902) already showed this exact approach.

Comment: @Default Sorry, I didn't noticed. He was faster than me :-)

Comment: @Default I added some extra information that could be helpful to the user.

Comment: The question *specifically* mentions that order is not an issue.  That said, defining a custom equality comparer is *not* how you'd go about handling that.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I read it. I thought that some extra information about how things work would be useful for the user (also if in the future he'll need to perform a comparison considering the order). Is not? What is the alternative then?